# What technical issues need to be considered when choosing between full wave (two diodes) or bridge rectifier (four diodes)?

Tags: diodes, rectifier

I've been reading (searching the net) on the differences between the two:

- It seems a bridge rectifier is more efficient in terms of the transformer construction.
- The bridge rectifier has a bigger voltage drop because of the two diodes (maximum of .7 each)
- Ripple is higher on a bridge rectifier

For an end user, I feel the transformer construction advantage might be not as useful.

Are there any other electrical advantages/disadvantages of one or the other? Is the current output the same/similar?

Comment: Edited. ...............................

Comment: If you use a full wave (2 diode) rectifier across centre tapped 12+12V windings you will end up with 12*sqrt(2) peak output, about 17V if smoothed by a capacitor. If you use a bridge rectifier across a 24V winding then you will get twice this, about 34V smoothed. With a bridge rectifier you don't need two windings, a single 24VAC @ 12.5A would work just as well. Or 12VAC @ 25A if it was the lower voltage/higher current you required.

Comment: If you need 12.5A rms rated secondary in the non-center-tapped case, then you should use a 12.5 * 0.7 = 8.75A rms rating for the alternative center-tapped transformer, not 6.25 A rms. So, perhaps the alternative transformers do not have the same weight or price.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, with two diodes and 2x 12VAC you'll get around 16V peak minus the ripple, maximum DC current about 12.5A = 200W.

In the second case, with a full wave rectifier (assuming you connect the secondaries in parallel) you would get about 32V minus the ripple, maximum DC current 7.75A = 248W.

---

Maybe you **meant** to use the transformers the opposite way you said. In that case with the 2x12VAC in series and full bridge rectifier you'd have about 32V minus ripple, maximum DC current 7.75A or 248W.

And in the second case, with 2 diodes and the two 24V windings center grounded, you'd get about 33V minus ripple, maximum DC current 6.25A or 206W.

As you can see the two diode version gives you a bit more voltage but uses the transformer significantly less efficiently even allowing for less loss in the diodes.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original post that I need V+/V- (which I added in the original post). So I what I wrote is correct.

Comment: That's a **totally** different case. If the loads are equally balanced then the transformer is used just as efficiently in the two diode arrangement. If the loads are greatly different it more resembles the above-described situation.

Answer (score 4):

> to an end user/builder, does it matter if the rectifier section is full wave (2 diodes) vs bridge rectifier (4 diodes)?

To an *end user* there is at least one advantage to using a center tapped transformer and two diodes over using a (4) diode bridge. The output of the center-tapped transformer, 2 diodes and smoothing capacitor combination, if the center tap is connected to ground (or neutral) as it commonly is, will be relatively free of common mode AC "ghost" voltage relative to ground.

On the other hand, a transformer without a secondary center tap, feeding a (4) diode bridge followed by a smoothing capacitor (aka "bulk" capacitor) "passes along" common mode AC voltage from input to output. The common mode input voltage to such a circuit is the common mode voltage of a mains supply. Because one leg of single-phase mains power is (in the US at least) bonded to ground, such single-phase mains power has an AC common mode voltage relative to ground of approximately half the differential mode voltage.

Although the inputs to the diode bridge in this topology are somewhat isolated from the mains power by the transformer, capacitance between the primary and secondary windings of a transformer will result in a "ghost" AC common mode voltage in the secondary, and consequently in the output of the power supply.

The following circuit and simulated oscillogram illustrates this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmVmXI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Here V(C3.nA)-V(C3.nB) (in brown) is the differential mode output voltage (across RL) and (V(C3.nA)-V(C3.nB))/2 (in blue) is the common mode output voltage relative to the mains neutral (and hence approximately to ground).

The ghost AC common mode voltage in the outputs of a psu with a 4 diode bridge can be particularly problematic in the case of audio equipment.  Such ghost common mode voltage, can be a significant source of hum/buzz.

For other applications, such as phone chargers, common mode AC appearing in the output, especially if the common mode impedance is relatively high, may not be problematic.

There are other differences between using center-tapped transformers and two diodes, vs non-center-tapped transformers and 4 diodes,

One drawback of using the center-tapped transformer topology is the extra weight and possibly cost and possibly bulk, of a center-tapped transformer.  For example, a 12V secondary used with a 4-diode bridge would need to be replaced with a 12-0-12V center-tapped transformer for 2 diode rectification. The secondary coil needs to have twice as many turns. The *average* current in each half of the center-tapped secondary will be half of the average current in the non-center-tapped secondary. However, **and this is important,** the *RMS* current in each half of the secondary will be 0.707 times the RMS current in the non-center-tapped secondary. It is the *RMS* current that determines the ohmic losses in a wire, and it is the *RMS* value that is used is sizing the wire needed for the current in a transformer secondary. So, the center-tapped secondary requires twice the number of turns, but about 0.707 times the cross section, so it is likely to need somewhere around 1.4 times the amount of copper. The number is not exact, because not all turns are the same length. So, barring something unusual, the center-tapped transformer will be heavier, and likely more expensive, and possibly larger. If weight, bulk and price are not a concern, then the center-tapped transformer configuration is probably a clear win. But often one or more of these factors *is* a concern.

Another technical issue is the extra voltage drop in a 4-diode bridge, (2 diode drops) vs the center-tapped transformer solution (1 diode voltage drop). The voltage drop directly relates to heat production in the PSU, and efficiency loss.

Comment: If weight and price are equal (or not an issue) I would always prefer the center-tapped- transformer with 2 diodes solution.

Comment: @mrjayviper I have added information on the _RMS_ value of the currents through the   halves of a center-tapped transformer secondary. You may wish to re-evaluate whether you are comparing the correct transformers, and whether transformers of appropriate ratings have the same weight and price for appropriately rated center-tapped vs non-center-tapped transformers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to achieve full-wave rectification in a dual-voltage power supply using only two diodes.

A bridge rectifier is a must.

[image]

Comment: Arguably, there is the full wave doubler circuit, which uses two diodes -- but it's full wave with respect to the total, and only half wave with respect to each series capacitor. I suppose that might still be acceptable in some applications. (Not disagreeing with the claim, just interesting that a near exception exists.)

Comment: Yes, Tim, that dual positive/negative supply would be half wave.